Need help building Access query within multiple tables
I am building a database for users of our computer systems. Each system has multiple users with different account access levels. I would like to be able to build a query that will ask the person who is doing the query to enter in identifying information. For example I have the following tables
Table for PC1



UserName
Last Name
First Name
Access Level




User 1
Smith
John
User


User 2
Jones
Paul
User


User 3
Adams
Micheal
User


User 4
Edwards
James
Admin



Table for PC2



UserName
Last Name
First Name
Access Level




User 1
Smith
John
User


User 2
Edwards
James
Admin


User 3
Edwards
James
User


User 4
Jones
Paul
User


User 5
Reid
George
User


User 6
Markle
April
Manager


User 7
Brown
Stephen
User



Table for PC3



UserName
Last Name
First Name
Access Level




User 1
Smith
John
User


User 2
Adams
Micheal
User


User 3
Brown
Stephen
User


User 4
Markle
April
Manager


User 5
Edwards
James
Admin



So, I'd like to be able to query
Last name: Edwards
First name: James
And have the query give me all lines where those two values are meet and add the name of the PC in the front of the results. Like this.



Computer
Username
Last Name
First Name
Access Level




PC1
User 4
Edwards
James
Admin


PC2
User 2
Edwards
James
Admin


PC2
User 3
Edwards
James
User


PC3
User 5
Edwards
James
Admin



If this has to be done by using a query, report or VBA. Any of these options would be acceptable. I was thinking I might have to do this by using a macro but if it is possible using the built in functions of Access, I think it would be easier. I just am not familiar enough with Access to know where to begin. I have tried the Query Wizard but it only looks for duplicates in a single table. I was also thinking that I could have all of the tables populated into a hidden table and then have the query perform the duplicate search on the combined table. Any insight would be appreciated on this matter.

Reconsider this table design. All three tables should be a single table with a PC identifier. Consider creating such a table with UNION. Further normalization would be to store names in a single user table and referenced in PC table with UserID Queries will be then much simpler.

Hello,
Thank you for the information and the suggestion. There is a part of the Database that I left out. There is an additional table that list all of the PC names and each name in the list is a hyperlink to the user list to that particular PC. This table also has links to external documents and other key information for each system. We'd like to keep these table separate for quick auditing. But I could create a new table that is a combination of all of the tables to then run a query on that new table and then hide that table from view.

I would use four tables to represent this:
Users

ID (PK) - AutoNumber
LastName
FirstName


Systems

ID (PK) - AutoNumber
System


AccessLevels

ID (PK) - AutoNumber
AccessLevel


SystemAccessInfo

SystemID  (PK) - Number
AccessID  (PK) - Number
UserID    (PK) - Number
UserName


I'd then have a query to pull it together:
SELECT  Users.ID AS UserID,
        System,
        UserName,
        LastName,
        FirstName,
        AccessLevel
FROM    ((SystemAccessInfo INNER JOIN Systems ON SystemAccessInfo.SystemID = Systems.ID)
                           INNER JOIN Users ON SystemAccessInfo.UserID = Users.ID)
                           INNER JOIN AccessLevels ON SystemAccessInfo.AccessID = AccessLevels.ID  

Create a continuous form to hold the UserDetail with a Record Source of the query.

Create another single form to hold just the first and last names with a Record Source  to the Users table and drag the UserDetail into that as a subform.
Link the Master/Child fields - ID to UserID and you're good to go:

